# Position absolute, top right hand corner (resizing)

Tags: html, css

Should be really simple... I thought.

I have a set up as such:

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="a1">THE FIRST</div>
   <div id="a2">THE SECOND</div>
</div>
```

I want the entire main div to be positioned at the top right hand corner of my screen and when I resize the browser, I want it to STAY there. I'm not talking fixed positioning - Just absolute.

However, this css isn't working. Any ideas?

```
#main {
        position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:300;
    min-width:0;
    width:8%;
}

#main #a1 {
    position:absolute;
    background: #082540;
    z-index: 300;
    right:0;
    top:40px;
}

#main #a2 {
    position:absolute;
    background: #082540;
    z-index: 300;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
```

** EDIT **

If I put the div at the top right hand, I want it to disappear (like "fixed") when I bring the browser in from right to left.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter, that is why your `#1` and `#2` styles are not applying, change them to something like `#a1` or `#a2`

**UPDATE**:
Just add `float:right;` to your `#main` div

Working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jY6w3/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip - still no luck.

Comment: Thanks - how do I make that entire div stay positioned at the top right hand corner during resize? I dont want it to remain at top right hand corner if resized.

Comment: You've just write a contradiction, check your last comment please clarify what are you seeing wrong in the fiddle I posted, I resize the window and the div stays top-right which I thought was your intention.

Comment: Why don't you use position:fixed if you want it to stay there?

Comment: I need the position of the div to be top right hand corner, fixed, but doesn't move at all during page scrolling and page resizing. I guess that's the best way to put it. Fixed positioning would just result in the div staying in position during screen scroll.